# How to prove:$1+\frac\alpha {1!}+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}\cdots$ converges when$\alpha>0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion

How to prove that $1+\frac\alpha {1!}+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}\cdots$ converges when $\alpha>0$?

My solution:
Taylor expansion by Cauthy's formula for the remainder term:
$1+\frac\alpha {1!}x+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!}x^2+\cdots+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}x^n+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n)}{n!}(1+\xi)^{\alpha-n-1}(x-\xi)^nx$

since \begin{align}r_n=&\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n)}{n!}(1+\xi)^{\alpha-n-1}(x-\xi)^nx\\=&\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\frac\alpha n-1)(\frac{x-\xi}{1+\xi})^{n}(1+\xi)^{\alpha-1}x\\=& \alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\frac\alpha n-1)[(\frac{1-\xi}{1+\xi})^{n}(1+\xi)^{\alpha-1}]\end{align}

When $k>N_0,1-\frac\alpha k>0,|\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\frac\alpha n-1)|=C\exp\{\sum\limits_{k=N_0}^n\ln(1-\frac\alpha k)\}=C\exp\{\sum\limits_{k=N_0}^n(-\frac\alpha k+\frac\beta {k^2}+o(\frac1{k^2})) \}\to 0$;

Since $(\frac{1-\xi}{1+\xi})^{n}(1+\xi)^{\alpha-1} $ is bounded as $n\to \infty$, we conclude $r_n\to 0$;

I think the solution is complicated and wonder if we have a more brief proof, probably without using taylor expansion?

If the solution above is not correct, feel free to point out my mistakes.

Comment: What's $\alpha$? If $\alpha=-1$ it doesn't converge I assume $\alpha>0$?

Comment: $\alpha>0$ it converges in [-1,1],$\alpha<0$ it converges in (-1,1),here only consider $\alpha >0$

Comment: Starting from some $n_0$ we have the series alternate between positive and negative general terms, so Dirichlet should be straightforward.

Comment: it can be done with Leibniz criterion : the series is alternating (for $n>\alpha$), the absolute values of the terms decrease (it's enough to take the ratio of two consecutive ones and to see that it's less than 1), and finally they converge to 0, but that I can see only by taking their logs and comparing with the harmonic series, just as you did

Comment: @user8268 We can compare the top absolutepart after $n_0$ with $(n-n_0)!$ so the general term acts like $1/n^{n_0}$ it's easiest to see when $\alpha<1, n_0=1$ then term by term comparison with $1\cdot 2\cdots (n-1)$ ignoring the first term $\alpha$.

Comment: In general, if $0\le b_n<1$ then $\prod_n (1-b_n)=0 \iff \sum_n b_n=\infty .$ So $\prod_{n>1+\alpha}(1-\frac {1+\alpha}{n})=0 \iff \sum_{n>1+\alpha}\frac {1+\alpha}{n}=\infty.$ So the sequence of absolute values of the terms goes to $0$ and is also eventually monotonic, so use the hint from @user8268...... Another general result is that if $c_n\ge 0$ then $\prod_n (1+c_n)=\infty \iff \sum_n c_n=\infty.$

Comment: @user8268. See my previous comment.

Comment: @kingW3 When $n_0\geq 2$, we can't easily conclude the coefficient part of $1/n^{n_0} $ is bounded, so we may have problem using Dirichlet?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet How would you prove the two general results?

Comment: $\prod (1+c_n)=\infty\Leftarrow \sum c_n=\infty$ won't be true because the LHS might doesn't have a limit, but they do convergent and divergent(not necessarily to infinite, might oscillate) at the same time.

Comment: (1). If $c_n\ge 0$ then $\exp (\sum_{n=1}^Mc_n)=\prod_{n=1}^M\exp c_n\ge$ $\prod_{n=1}^M(1+c_n)\ge 1+\sum_{n=1}^mc_n$

Comment: (2). If $0\le b_n<1$ then: $(i).$ If $b_n\ge 1/2$ for infinitely many $n$ then $\prod_n(1-b_n)=0$ and $\sum_n b_n=\infty$.... $(ii)$. If $b_n\ge 1/2$ for only finitely many $n$ then remove the terms for which $b_n\ge 1/2$ so that we need only consider the case where $b_n<1/2$ for all n. For this case, let $1-b_n=(1+c_n)^{-1}.$ Then $b_n\le c_n=\frac {b_n}{1-b_n}\le 2b_n. $ Now apply (1) to $c_n$ from my previous comment.

Comment: I get that. Thank you@DanielWainfleet!